# Which are the basic steps of the stock price forecasting using ARIMA model in R?

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I am very new to this field and I want to learn forecasting of stock price using R. Please let me know which are the step should I follow?

If someone know tutorial links for forecasting in R then it will be good.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/7

Comment: ARIMA and cousins are the *wrong* type of models for stock prices. Read an intro level text on financial engineering.

Comment: @horaceT: Which is the best model to forecast with stock price in R ?

Comment: @Napster First, few professional traders try to model prices, they model *returns* of stocks. Do some google search on CAPM, factor models, that will get you started.

Answer (score -1):

To get started you'll want to load the forecast package and convert your dependent variable to a time series.

For monthly prices you could do the following:

```
library(forecast)
ts_price <- ts(price, start = c(year, month), frequency = 12)
```

For defining more complex frequencies (daily, hourly, multiple) see the following [post](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/dailydata/) by Prof. Hyndman. You'll probably want to define something more complex for stock prices depending on your forecast horizon.

Next you can easily fit and forecast an ARIMA Model using the `auto.arima` and `forecast` functions from the `forecast` package.

```
fit <- auto.arima(ts_price, stepwise = F, approximation = F)
fc  <- forecast(fit, h = 12, level = c(75, 85, 95))
plot(fc)
```

To run a working example of the above on your computer just replace `ts_price` with `AirPassengers` to use one of the included `time series` data sets. Eliminating `stepwise = F` and `approximation = F` will significantly improve run time.

Comment: You really need to read up on the basics of financial asset pricing. Stock prices are (almost) continuous time Brownian motion. The basic assumption behind the textbook time series models is stationarity, which Brownian motion violates.

Comment: The question asked specifically using ARIMA in R. Perhaps you should have read the title.